# How can I read the contents of a word document to determine if they contain a keyword?

Tags: microsoft-word, powershell

I have a set of 6000 word documents. I was trying to think of ways to search the content of each word document against a keyword. Then I would print out these results to store them later. This would quickly speed up what would be a manual process. As I'm hoping to categorize a large amount of documents. I noticed that I can already do something like this in the advanced search function in the windows file explorer. So I wondering if there's something on-board the PC that would allow me to accomplish this task in powershell. Also where should I start in terms of what functions I should use.

Obviously I need to use loop. What should I use for reading the contents of the word documents, and how do I write the results to a file?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The post
[powershell script to find a string in word document and move to other location if exists](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ac425760-beb9-442f-9651-41428e23fc41/powershell-script-to-find-a-string-in-word-document-and-move-to-other-location-if-exists?forum=winserverpowershell)
contains the following script. I have modified it to remove the part that
moves the found document.
You could replace the `$source` folder and the keyword `Security` inside the script,
or make them into parameters:

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$source = 'D:\source'
$docs = Get-ChildItem -Path $source | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '.docx'}
foreach ($doc in $docs)
{
    if ($word.Documents.Open($doc.FullName).Content.Find.Execute('Security'))
    {
        Write-Host "$doc contains 'Security'"
    }
    $word.Application.ActiveDocument.Close()
}
```

Another and far more complex script is described in the article
[Find All Word Documents that Contain a Specific Phrase](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/find-all-word-documents-that-contain-a-specific-phrase/).

Comment: Does this open a window 6000 times?

Comment: Better use `-Filter *.docx` to select only Word documents (If using RE based -match => `'\.docx$'`).

Comment: No, it only produces one line of output to the console for each document found. But it will open and close 6000 documents, which will take some time.

Answer (score 1):

If the directory containing the documents you want to search is an [indexed location](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/58756-add-remove-search-index-locations-windows-10-a.html) it is much faster to query the Windows Search index rather than opening and searching each document separately.  By default the Word filter indexes contents and not just filesnames.

Based on the structure in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340410/connect-to-windows-desktop-search-on-remote-machine) you would want a SQL statement something like this - obviously changing the `SCOPE` to the directory you want to search and `TESTSTRING` to whatever word you are looking for.

```
SELECT System.ItemName, System.ItemPathDisplay, System.ItemType 
FROM SYSTEMINDEX 
WHERE SCOPE='C:\Test\' 
AND System.ItemType <> 'Directory'
AND CONTAINS(System.Search.Contents,'*TESTSTRING*') 
AND CONTAINS(System.FileName,'*.docx')
```

As described [here](https://www.petri.com/how-to-query-the-windows-search-index-using-sql-and-powershell) you can extract details of the documents matching these criteria using powershell as follows :

```
$sql = "SELECT System.ItemName, System.ItemPathDisplay, System.ItemType FROM SYSTEMINDEX WHERE SCOPE = 'C:\Test\' AND CONTAINS(System.Search.Contents,'*TESTSTRING*') AND CONTAINS(System.FileName,'*.docx')"

$provider = "provider=search.collatordso;extended properties='application=windows';"
$connector = new-object system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter -argument $sql, $provider
$dataset = new-object system.data.dataset

if ($connector.fill($dataset)) { $dataset.tables[0] | select-object System.ItemName, System.ItemPathDisplay, System.ItemType  | format-table -autosize * }
```

For example :

[image: Screenshot]

To output the results to a file instead of the screen change the last line to use `out-file` instead of `format-table`.  For example this would output the results to a file called *Results.txt* on your desktop.

```
if ($connector.fill($dataset)) { $dataset.tables[0] | select-object System.ItemName, System.ItemPathDisplay, System.ItemType  | out-file ~/desktop/Results.txt }
```